# C++: Why is std::vector::data member function introduced?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, member-functions

I was looking at the STL's vector container from below link. And it is mentioned that one of the new member functions added (with C++11) to this container is `vector::data`, which returns a pointer to the memory array used internally.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/

The example code given in above link also shows it usage, but it seemed that all that could be done with iterators too.

Is there any specific reason for introduction of this member function?

Comment: So you could pass it to a function only accepting pointers.

Comment: simply for the context where a pointer is needed. All [ContiguousContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousContainer) **can** be accessed by pointers correctly, so we have *data*.

Comment: the iterators obtained cannot be converted to pointers (they should for `std::vector::iterator` in my opinion). introducing `data()` was basically the STL way to say that `std::vectors` will use contiguous memory in the post C++11 standard. Before that, people did things like `&v[0]`, which even if it was ok, it was not clear what is the intention. BTW, use `.data()` if you have to, use `begin()` otherwise.

Comment: @PasserBy, makes sense but i just want to know if that is the "specifc" reason why it was created or is there is some other use.

Comment: @Constructor, I just think providing access to internally managed memory (by container) seems like a dangerous thing to do, could you please provide any code snippet that makes its use reasonable.

Comment: @Constructor, that's right, and by symmetry all ContiguousIterators (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousIterator) should have a `data` function was well. All strided iterators should have a `base` and `stride` function, and all block iterators should have a `block` and `position` function. etc.

Comment: @pasha, that is right it is a dangerous thing to do, it breaks some abstractions of `std::vector`, that it why you shouldn't use if you can avoid it, but sometimes you have to. If you call a C-function that takes an array you basically don't have any other option. Suppose for example that you want to run an FFT on your data, chances are that you are going to use a C-library for that, which will take a pointer and a size (not an iterator). http://www.fftw.org/doc/Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs.html . Of course you can do all sorts of dangerous things with `data`, for example deallocate it.

Comment: @pasha Yes, so you should avoid it if you can. But in fact, you may cannot always avoid using pointers to access a contiguous container.

Comment: @alfC and Constructor, pardon me but I'm not familiar with ContiguousIterators, could you please let me know a case where .data() (Or ContiguousContainer) is useful. I just can't get my head around as to why pointers are explicitly involved in STL, have to mention again it seems dangerous and makes it less generic.

Comment: @alfC thanks for that example, that (passing pointer to C-like functions) is the only thing that came to my mind first. I just want to know if that is the only reason.

Comment: @pasha, I think the answer to you original question and the request in the last comment is repeated in many different forms already. In a perfect world where only C++ exists, you are right, iterators are enough, unfortunatelly C++ sometimes has to communicate with other languages, such as C, Fortran, and Python, and communicate with OS devices. In that context, pointers are the lingua franca that allows such communication. So, yes, the main reason for `data()` is this one, other pure-C++ hacks or non-portable optimizations might be done using this.

Comment: Handing out a pointer isn't any more dangerous than handing out a reference.

Answer (score 2):

from the comments:

- std::vector is a [ContiguousContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousContainer) and can be accessed by pointers.
- access by pointer can be needed by C-like functions

There is potential for failure:

- deleting the pointer, will make the vecotr invalid and will create problems when the vector is destroyed.
- everything that leads to reallocation of the underlying data in vector (like adding elements or shrinking) will make the pointer to a dangling pointer. (As pointed out in the comments, this is also true for iterators and references)

Comment: Note that regular iterator might also be invalidated by some operation (as adding element to vector).

Comment: @Jarod42  Yes, but references and pointers can also be invalidated, not only iterators.

Comment: @Constructor: From reading the answer, we might thing that iterator is safer than pointer with reallocation (Ignoring the deleting pointer issue). I just wanted to pointed that both are/might be invalidated when adding element to vector.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `data()` function was introduced for completeness of interface and convenience.

This way we do not need to resort to the ugliness of `&vec[0]` or `&vec.front()`.

Moreover, getting a pointer to the underlying data is useful in many applications, like interfacing with C code or some external libraries, or in embedded contexts for example.

Comment: And that avoid the debate to know if `&vec[0]` is UB for empty vector or not. :-)